# How to change border color on focus?

Tags: html, css, forms

By clicking inside the input field or focus on the input field, how to change the border color.

HTML

```
<div className="col-md-12">
   <div className="form-group">
      <label for="Street_Address">Street address</label>
      <input type="text" className="form-control" id="Street_Address"  placeholder="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input:focus
{
    border: 1px solid #1670BE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #1670BE;
    outline-offset: 0px;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], textarea, select { 
    outline: none;
}
```

---

When the element is focussed, the User Agent (browser) by default sets an outline. So, to prevent it, you need to override it as shown above

Comment: pls explain your code snippet so that many people will understand the solution. i understand that it may be right solution. Bit explanation is needed

Answer (score 12):

try this also.

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: next time instead of using <br> between codes try using Ctrl + K or the code button above.

Comment: you have to explain your code snippet so that many people will understand the solution. i understand that it may be right solution. Bit explanation is needed

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes what looks like a border is really a border shadow as in the case of Bootstrap, so you would use:

```
#myelement:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
input{
        border:none;
    }

input:focus, textarea:focus
{
    border: 1px solid #1670BE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #1670BE;
    outline-offset: 0px;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to answer an almost 10-year old question, it would be preferable for your answer to contain an explanation of what it is you're posting.